# onPrepareOptionsMenu called after onCreateView

Tags: android

I have fragment which shows menu on action bar.

onPrepareOptionsMenu() is getting called after onCreateView()

Is that normal behavior? Is there any documentation that show this kind of stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its normal since `onCreateView()` first inflate the layout and then you can prepare the menu items and add listener to it.